# Como implementar un evento/onclick a un boton solo con DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

Estoy creando una página desde 0 solo utilizando el DOM(sin modificar HTML) y quiero crear un botón para que al seleccionar un valor de una lista (también creada con DOM), muestre las propiedades del valor seleccionad (un JSON creado)

Esto es lo que tengo.. cuando añado la función mostrarDatos, me muestra la información  directamente sin haber pulsado el botón antes.

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.innerHTML = "PARTE 2 DEL EJERCICIO";
body.appendChild(h1);

let select = document.createElement("select");
body.appendChild(select);

for(let i = 0; i<personas.length; i++){
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = personas[i].nombre + " " + personas[i].apellidos;
    select.appendChild(option);
}

let botonMostrar = document.createElement("button");
botonMostrar.type = "button";
botonMostrar.style.marginLeft = "15px";
botonMostrar.innerHTML = "Mostrar datos";
//botonMostrar.onclick = "mostrarDatos()";
body.appendChild(botonMostrar);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Casi lo tienes, solo te falta añadir la funciona a ejecutar como referencia en vez de un `string`.

Es decir:

```
botonMostrar.onclick = mostrarDatos
```

Ejemplo completo:

```js
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.innerHTML = "PARTE 2 DEL EJERCICIO";
body.appendChild(h1);

let select = document.createElement("select");

body.appendChild(select);

let personas = [
  {nombre: "Nombre", apellidos: "Apellido"},
  {nombre: "Nombre2", apellidos: "Apellido2"},
]

for(let i = 0; i<personas.length; i++){
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = personas[i].nombre + " " + personas[i].apellidos;
    select.appendChild(option);
}

let botonMostrar = document.createElement("button");

function mostrarDatos(){
  console.log("Ejecutado")
}

botonMostrar.type = "button";
botonMostrar.style.marginLeft = "15px";
botonMostrar.innerHTML = "Mostrar datos";
botonMostrar.onclick = mostrarDatos
body.appendChild(botonMostrar);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @MitaCloud . Ya lo he conseguido, no lo veia!!